# Uploading image to web service in .net

Tags: .net, image, web, service, uploading

I want to create a product in my web that have a name,price category and image but i dont know how to upload that image in web service.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void CreateEditProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            int? id = __helper.ToNullableInt(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Id"].ToString());
            string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Name"].ToString();
            int price = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Price"].ToString());
            string image = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Image"].ToString();
            int categoryId = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["CategoryId"].ToString());

            Service1Client wcfObj = new Service1Client();
            product addedProduct = wcfObj.CreateEditProduct(id, name, price, image, categoryId);

            Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.SeeOther;
            Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addedProduct));
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.SeeOther;
            Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
        }
    }
```